# Closed form of recurrence relation $F(n) = 2 + F(n-1) + F(n-2)$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I was figuring out an answer to the question,

> How many Boolean arrays of length $n$ could be formed if there are to
>   be no two falses in a row?

I could see that it boils down to a Fibonacci like equation,

$$F(n) = 2 + F(n-1) + F(n-2)$$

But I am unable to find a closed form for this recursion. May be I am following the wrong direction here.

Please help.

Comment: You would need two initial conditions to solve this uniquely, i.e. $F(0)$ and $F(1)$ for example. Can you provide these?

Comment: Hi. Yes. For this problem, we have F(1) = 1, F(2) = 3.

Comment: Your recurrence is incorrect, I’m afraid, which means that the accepted answer is also wrong (since it correctly solved the recurrence that you gave).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, You are right. It turned out to be straight forward Fibonacci sequence. I am just starting with these kind of problems. I definitely should have been more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence stated in the question is incorrect. If it were correct, you’d have $$F(3)=2+1+3=6\;,$$ but in fact $F(3)=5$; the valid strings are $111,110,101,011$, and $010$, and the invalid strings are $000,001$, and $100$, where $0$ represents **false**, and $1$ represents **true**.

This is a very good example of a problem in which a little numerical experimentation pays off. It’s not hard to compute the first few $F(n)$ by hand:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4\\
F(n):&1&2&3&5&8
\end{array}$$

They look suspiciously like the Fibonacci numbers, but offset by two places: if the Fibonacci numbers are denoted by $f_n$ (with $f_0=0$ and $f_1=1$), the table suggests the conjecture that $F(n)=f_{n+2}$. This conjecture would be proved if could show that $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$ for $n\ge 2$.

This is fairly straightforward. Say that a Boolean string is *good* if it does not contain two adjacent instances of **false**. Let $\sigma$ be a good Boolean string of length $n$, and let $\tau$ be the substring obtained by deleting the last element of $\sigma$.

- If $\sigma$ ends in **true**, $\tau$ can be any good string of length $n-1$; there are $F(n-1)$ of these, so there are $F(n-1)$ good Boolean strings of length $n$ that end in **true**.
- If $\sigma$ ends in **false**, the last element of $\tau$ must be **true** (because $\sigma$ is good), but the first $n-2$ elements of $\tau$ can be any good string of length $n-2$. There are $F(n-2)$ of these, so there are $F(n-2)$ good Boolean strings of length $n$ that end in **false** (and hence actually in **true** **false**).

These are the only possibilities, and they’re disjoint, so $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. And since we already know that $F(0)=f_2$ and $F(1)=f_3$, it follows immediately that $F(n)=f_{n+2}$ for all $n\ge 0$. We can now use any of the various [closed form expressions for the Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted instead of mine. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Given that
$$
F(n + 2) = 2 + F(n + 1) + F(n)
$$
we have
$$
G(n + 2) = G(n + 1) + G(n)
$$
where $G(n) = F(n) + 2$. Because $G(1) = 3$ and $G(2) = 5$, we have
$$
G(n) = H(n + 3)
$$
where $H(n)$ is Fibonacci sequence with $H(1) = 1$ and $H(2) = 1$. The closed form then can be derived from the closed form of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP’s recurrence is incorrect.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for pointing out the mistake. You are right. :)

Comment: It's too bad, because your solution of the OP's recurrence is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to form the homogeneous solution as a sum of powers obtained from the characteristic equation, and to add a particular solution.

$$f_n-f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}=2$$

corresponds to

$$r^2-r-1=0$$ which has the same roots ($\phi$ and $-\phi^{-1}$ as that of Fibonacci), and is solved by

$$f_n=-2.$$

Hence the general solution

$$f_n=A\phi^n+B(-\phi)^{-n}-2.$$

$A$ and $B$ are determined by plugging the initial conditions,

$$\begin{cases}f_0=A+B-2\\f_1=\phi A-\phi^{-1}B-2.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score -1):

I like to do these recurrences in terms of generating functions:

Let $A(x) = \sum_{n\geq1} F(n)x^n$ for some $x<1$. Now take your recurrence, 
$$
F(n+2) = 2 + F(n+1) + F(n),
$$
multiply it by $x^n$ and sum over all $n$. We get
$$
\frac{A(x) - x^2 F(2) - xF(1)}{x^2} = \frac{2x}{1-x} + \frac{A(x)-xF(1)}{x} + A(x),
$$
which, after solving for $A(x)$, gives
$$
A(x) = \frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)(1-x-x^2)} = \frac{x+2}{1-x-x^2} - \frac{2}{1-x}.
$$
It is well known that the generating functions for the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers are
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}, \quad L(x) = \frac{2-x}{1-x-x^2}
$$
Hence, 
$$
A(x) = 2f(x) + L(x) - \frac{2}{1-x}.
$$
Recall now that $F(n)$ are the coefficients of the series expansion of $A(x)$, and thus
$$
F(n) = 2f_n + L_n - 2,
$$
where $f_n$ and $L_n$ are the $n$th Fibonacci and Lucas numbers respectively.